# Invalid use of flexible array member

Tags: c++

I've got a problem when i'm programming.

```
struct skills {
    int SnCrypt;
    char* Soutput;
    int Soptind;
    int Sdecrypt;
    int Sargc;
    char* Spassword;
    char *const Sargv[];
};

struct skills* initSkills(int nCrypt, char* password, char *const argv[], char* output, int optind, int decrypt, int argc) {
    struct skills* skill;
    skill->SnCrypt = nCrypt;
    skill->Spassword = password;
    skill->Sargv = argv;
    skill->Soutput = output;
    skill->Soptind = optind;
    skill->Sdecrypt = decrypt;
    skill->Sargc = argc;

    return skill;
}
```

And gcc tell me

> invalid use of flexible array member

for the line `skill->Sargv = argv;`.

I don't understand how could I point the value pointed by `char *const argv[]` by an other pointer? I'm aware that I surely must `malloc` the `skill->Sargv` pointer but how? Like this `(char const*)malloc(sizeof(argv[]))`?

Comment: The code doesn't look like C++ and certainly not C#, maybe it's C?

Comment: @anatolyg Yes, flexible arrays is a C feature.

Comment: You don't need to restate `struct` when declaring a `struct` variable (if this really is C++), and you need to allocate memory for it (otherwise your application will crash).

Answer (score 7):

The answer below is in C, which appears to be more appropriate than C++ in the context of this question.

You're basically not supposed to declare an array with an unknown number of entries (AKA "flexible array"). The only way to do so - exactly as you did - is by declaring it as **the last field** in the structure.

It sort of indicates that the size of **the entire structure** is unknown.

And being as such, you cannot statically instantiate this structure:

```
struct skills x; // will generate a compilation error
```

Instead, you can only instantiate it dynamically. For example, here is an instance of this structure with its `Sargv` array large enough to accommodate 5 elements:

```
struct skills* x = malloc(sizeof(struct skills)+5*sizeof(char*));
```

**Having said all that, there are two options for you to fix your code:**

Option #1 - assuming that you are calling function `initSkills` with the `argv` of function `main` (which resides in memory throughout the entire lifetime of the program), you might as well declare:

```
struct skills
{
    ...
    char** const Sargv; // instead of 'char* const Sargv[]'
};
```

Option #2 - allocate the `struct skills` instance with its `Sargv` array large enough to accommodate `argc` elements, and then copy each element from the `argv` array into the `Sargv` array:

```
int i;
struct skills* skill = malloc(sizeof(struct skills)+argc*sizeof(char*));
...
for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
{
    skill->Sargv[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);
    strcpy(skill->Sargv[i],argv[i]);
}
return skill;
```

**Please note that you have an additional (unrelated) fix to apply in your code:**

Change this:

```
skill->Spassword = password;
```

To this:

```
skill->Spassword = malloc(strlen(password)+1);
strcpy(skill->Spassword,password);
```